# Gremlin Query Language: how to drop every vertex that is not edged to anything?

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

As the title suggests. How do I drop every vertex that does not have any edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
g.V().where(bothE().limit(1).count().is(lt(1)).drop()
```

or perhaps:

```
g.V().where(__.not(bothE())).drop()
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I wish you a great summer:)